# how to configure license for AHB

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database

How to calculate how many licenses required for Azure Hybrid Benefit.
below is the configuration for MSSQL db Sql database configuration below:-

```
General Purpose: Gen5, 2 vCore, 
Business Critical: Gen5, 16 vCores,
Business Critical: Gen5, 4 vCore,
Business Critical: Gen5, 8 vCores
```

Thanks

so we need these licenses for these MSSQL db where Azure hybrid license is already enabled:

```
General Purpose: Gen5, 2 vCore,    1 windows server  license require azure hybrid benefit is already enabled.
Business Critical: Gen5, 16 vCores, 16 windows server  license require azure hybrid benefit is already enabled.
Business Critical: Gen5, 4 vCore,   4 windows server license require azure hybrid benefit is already enabled. 
Business Critical: Gen5, 8 vCores   8 windows server license require azure hybrid benefit is already enable
```

For Azure database mysql server we have below details configured for these servers how many licenses we need to purchase

```
General Purpose, 2 vCore(s), 100 GB Gen 5
General Purpose, 4 vCore(s), 512 GB Gen 5
Memory Optimized, 4 vCore(s), 100 GB    Gen 5
General Purpose, 32 vCore(s), 512 GB    Gen 5
General Purpose, 4 vCore(s), 200 GB Gen 5
Memory Optimized, 16 vCore(s), 514 GB   Gen 5
General Purpose, 2 vCore(s), 200 GB Gen 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Licenses are purchased based on number of Cores. In the case of General Purpose you are using 2 vCores (GP5) and for Business Critical(BC5) you are using 28 vCores.

This [hybrid benefit calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/hybrid-benefit/#calculator) can help you. If I understand it correctly, you would need to have:

- 2 Standard SQL licenses to cover a 2 vCore GP5 DB and,
  [image]
- either 28 Enterprise SQL licenses or 112 Standard SQL licenses to cover the 28 vCores of the BC5.
  [image]

  [image]

You can also download and checkout the  [licensing datasheet](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/c/05c60185-ebdd-4472-895a-3d8e8da55682/SQL_Server_2019_Licensing_Datasheet.pdf) and [licensing guide](https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/2/9/e29a9331-965d-4faa-bd2e-7c1db7cd8348/SQL_Server_2019_Licensing_guide.pdf). See [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/sql-server/sql-server-2019-pricing) link for more info.

Comment: thanks Ked, i have enabled all the MSSQL db , azure hybrid license option, at our env we have these 4 configuration: for MSSQL db 1) GeneralPurpose: Gen5, 2Vcore, 2) Business critical: Gen5, 16vcores
3) Business critical ;Gen5, 4 Vcore, 4) BusinessCritical: Gen5,8Vcores.   we need to provide how many license required for Azure hybrid benefits for these MSSQL db configurations thanks

Answer (score 0):

The conversions for SQL Server Core Licenses to Azure SQL Database/Managed Instance vCores is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/news/expanded-ahb-rights-for-microsoft-sql-server#:%7E:text=%20%20%20%20Qualified%20License%20%20,Core%20License%3A1%20vCore%20%2010%20more%20rows%20).

Comment: Having MSSQL server configuration below:                                                             
General Purpose: Gen5, 2 vCore, 
Business Critical: Gen5, 16 vCores,
Business Critical: Gen5, 4 vCore,
Business Critical: Gen5, 8 vCores  for the sql servers, for these configuration we have multiple MSSQL servers configured, so for these configuration can you suggest pls, is for each Vcore we need 1 license each so for 4 vcore, 4 license is it

Comment: Its different between GP and BC.  For GP 1 Core License per 4 vCores.  For BC 1 Core License per 1 vCore.